# Custom customer account navigation page returning blank

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to add a custom customer account dashboard page but it keeps returning as a blank page

customer_account.xml:

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <title>PixelPin Connect</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-pixelpin" after="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">socialconnect/customer/index</argument>
                        <!--Also tried "socialconnect/customer-->
                        <argument translate="true" name="label" xsi:type="string">Pixelpin Connect</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

socialconnect_customer_index.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>PixelPin Connect</title>
        <css src="Inchoo_SocialConnect::inchoo_socialconnect/css/styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Pixelpin\Account" name="inchoo_socialconnect_pixelpin_account" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::account.phtml" cacheable="false"/>          
            <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Pixelpin\Button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_account_pixelpin_button" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::button.phtml" cacheable="false"/>  
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
namespace Inchoo\SocialConnect\Controller\Customer;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

public function execute() {
        $this->_view->loadlayout();

        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

system.log error stack:

```
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' element cannot be added as child to 'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'head.components' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'requirejs-config' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'translate-config' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'translate' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'js_cookies' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'skip_to_content.target' element cannot be added as child to 'main.content', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header-wrapper' element cannot be added as child to 'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'top.container' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.main.title' element cannot be added as child to 'columns.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.messages' element cannot be added as child to 'columns.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'content.top' element cannot be added as child to 'main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'content' element cannot be added as child to 'main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'content.aside' element cannot be added as child to 'main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'content.bottom' element cannot be added as child to 'main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.bottom' element cannot be added as child to 'page.bottom.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'footer' element cannot be added as child to 'footer-container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'absolute_footer' element cannot be added as child to 'before.body.end', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'cookie_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'google_analytics' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'logger' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'paypal.express-in-context.component' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header.container' and '' respectively. [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'skip_to_content.target' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'main.content' and '' respectively. [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.top' and '' respectively. [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'cookie_notices' tries to reorder itself towards 'global_notices', but their parents are different: 'after.body.start' and '' respectively. [] []
[2016-11-18 14:13:30] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'before.body.end'. [] []
```

etc/frontend/routes.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <router id="standard">
       <route id="inchoo_socialconnect" frontName="socialconnect">
                <module name="Inchoo_SocialConnect"/>
        </route>
   </router>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the logs indicate an issue with your layout file. So, I'd double-check that to ensure the file name is exactly correct, etc. As annoying as that is, it's how Magento 2 does it.

Also, could you perhaps be a little more specific about what you mean when you say "it keeps returning as a blank page"? Is that the customer dashboard, or your custom controller?

EDIT:

Since it's your custom controller that's coming back blank, here are a couple things you can try:

First, ensure that the system is actually finding your controller. The easiest way to do this is to insert this code into the beginning of your `execute()` method:

```
echo "I'm here!";
die();
```

If it is, then you should really analyze your layout file for errors. I noticed that you don't have an XML version declaration at the top of your files (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`) - it may not make a difference, but you can try to put it in and see if it helps.

ANOTHER EDIT:

The issue is with your `routes.xml` file. Magento uses the route id, not the frontName as the first part of a URL. This is counter-intuitive and I'm not sure why. In most cases, it makes sense to have them match, so change your file to this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <router id="standard">
        <route id="socialconnect" frontName="socialconnect">
            <module name="Inchoo_SocialConnect"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: it's my custom controller.

Comment: they do have '<?xml version="1.0"?>' at the top of the files, i just left them out

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure your controller is being hit?

Comment: I'm checking right now

Comment: Also, could you post your `routes.xml` file?

Comment: added routes.xml in edit

Comment: Is the routes.xml file in etc/frontend?

Comment: yes it is the routes.xml file in etc/frontend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48726/discussion-between-tjons-and-callum).

Answer (score 0):

tjons answer is not correct, in so far as Magento does *not* use the `routeId` as the first part of an URL. It uses the `frontName` as the first part of an URL, as advertised.

**However** the difference is when setting the page layout for such a route, Magento uses the `routeId` for the naming structure of the layout XMLs, *not* the `frontName`.

So if your `routes.xml` contains

```
<route id="inchoo_socialconnect" frontName="socialconnect">…</route>
```

then the layout XML needs to be named

```
inchoo_socialconnect_customer_index.xml
```

for example, instead of `socialconnect_customer_index.xml`.

The URL will still be `socialconnect/customer/index`.